# Identify chmod permissions

Tags: linux, putty

in Linux, how can I find the change mod permissions. For example, for the below permission, how would I identify its numbers

````
-rw-r--r-- 1
drwxr-xr-x 2
-rw-r--r-- 1
-rwxrwxr-x 1 
```
````

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`stat --format '%a' file`

Or a shorthand

`stat -c %a programs.png`

Where `-c` is a shorthand for `--format`